# Nodemailer works and then i get error greeting not received

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

If i send a test email, the first time everything will work perfectly and then after I will always get the greeting not received error.

No SMTP connection details were changed, if anyone could point out something I might be missing , I would greatly appreciate your help.

```
const ContactForm = asyncHandlerWrap( async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            name: "example",
            host: process.env.HOST,
            port: process.env.PORT_SMTP,
            secureConnection: true,
            logger:true,
            auth: {
              user: process.env.AUTH_NAME, 
              pass: process.env.AUTH_PASS, 
            },
        });

        transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
            if (error) {
              console.log("something wrong");
            } else {
              console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
            }
        });

        const mail = {
            from:process.env.AUTH_NAME,
            to:req.body.email,
            subject:req.body.subject,
            text:`Hello ${req.body.firstName} your submission has been received and one of our team members will contact you shortly`
        }

        const mail2 = {
            from:process.env.AUTH_NAME,
            to:'example@me.com',
            subject:req.body.subject,
            text:`${req.body.firstName} would like to know about ${req.body.subject}
            Message:
            ${req.body.message}

            You can contact them at:
            ${req.body.email}`
        }
        const resss = await axios.post(
            `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}&response=${req.body.captchaToken}`
        );

        console.log(resss)
      if (resss.data.success === true){
            transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, info) => {
                if (err) {
                  res.status(401).send({
                    status: 401,
                    message: err,
                  });
                  return;
                } else {
                    transporter.sendMail(mail2, (err, info) => {
                        if (err) {
                          res.status(401).send({
                            status: 401,
                            message: err,
                          });
                          return;
                        } else {
                          res.status(200).send({
                            status: 200,
                            message: "contact mail sent",
                            messageId: info.messageId,
                          });
                          return;
                        }
                      });
                  return;
                }
              });
          }else{
            res.status(400).send({
              status: 400,
              message: "email not sent",
            });
          }
        
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
        res.status(404).send({error:'something went wrong'})
    }
})

module.exports = ContactForm;
```

Im using a clients cPanel SMTP email settings, could there perhaps be an issue on that side ? Its just quite confusing it works perfectly the first time and then after that I get errors.

Here is working logs

```
[2022-01-13 10:46:39] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.7.1[client:6.7.1]
[2022-01-13 10:46:39] DEBUG [bvxzQQpSQys] Resolved MY HOST as server IP [cache hit]
[2022-01-13 10:46:39] INFO  [bvxzQQpSQys] Secure connection established to server IP
[2022-01-13 10:47:03] DEBUG [QaurmSSaTI] SMTP handshake finished
[2022-01-13 10:47:03] INFO  [QaurmSSaTI] User "example@me.com" authenticated
Server is ready to take our messages
[2022-01-13 10:47:03] DEBUG [QaurmSSaTI] Closing connection to the server using "end"
[2022-01-13 10:47:03] INFO  [QaurmSSaTI] Connection closed
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] DEBUG [bvxzQQpSQys] SMTP handshake finished
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] INFO  [bvxzQQpSQys] User "example@me.com" authenticated
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] INFO  Sending message <906dc927-79c8-febd-6907- 
a80d84bf5bd4@me.com> to <test@me.com>
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] INFO  [bvxzQQpSQys] <405 bytes encoded mime message (source 
size 402 bytes)>
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] DEBUG [bvxzQQpSQys] Closing connection to the server using 
"end"
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.7.1[client:6.7.1]
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] DEBUG [zQlN3dPe0] Resolved MY HOST as server IP [cache hit]
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] INFO  [bvxzQQpSQys] Connection closed
[2022-01-13 10:47:04] INFO  [zQlN3dPe0] Secure connection established to  server IP/ 
port 465
[2022-01-13 10:47:27] DEBUG [zQlN3dPe0] SMTP handshake finished
[2022-01-13 10:47:27] INFO  [zQlN3dPe0] User "example@me.com" authenticated
[2022-01-13 10:47:27] INFO  Sending message <3dc74212-3476-3721-e3e9- 
61029f9a1900@me.com to <example@me.com>
[2022-01-13 10:47:27] INFO  [zQlN3dPe0] <449 bytes encoded mime message (source size 
441 bytes)>
[2022-01-13 10:47:27] DEBUG [zQlN3dPe0] Closing connection to the server using "end"
[2022-01-13 10:47:27] INFO  [zQlN3dPe0] Connection closed
```

Here is failed logs

```
[2022-01-13 11:23:02] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.7.1[client:6.7.1]
[2022-01-13 11:23:02] DEBUG [tC8Bobgf0pY] Resolved MY HOST as server IP [cache hit]
[2022-01-13 11:23:02] INFO  [tC8Bobgf0pY] Secure connection established to Server IP/ 
port 465
[2022-01-13 11:23:31] ERROR [V2CGh8mmmiw] Greeting never received
[2022-01-13 11:23:31] DEBUG [V2CGh8mmmiw] Closing connection to the server using 
"end"
something wrong
[2022-01-13 11:23:32] ERROR [tC8Bobgf0pY] Greeting never received
[2022-01-13 11:23:32] DEBUG [tC8Bobgf0pY] Closing connection to the server using 
"end"
[2022-01-13 11:23:32] ERROR Send Error: Greeting never received
[2022-01-13 11:23:37] INFO  [V2CGh8mmmiw] Connection closed
[2022-01-13 11:23:38] INFO  [tC8Bobgf0pY] Connection closed
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone finds this in the future, the answer is to extend your greetingTimeout. The connection is established but the greeting is never received because it times out too fast.

Comment: How? I tried to add that still have the same error.
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
    port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
    secureConnection: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    greetingTimeout : 1000 * 50,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.SMTP_USER, // generated ethereal user
      pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS, // generated ethereal password
    },
  });